# How PHP interprets this code?

Tags: php, interpreter

I wanna know how php interprets this code. Is it something of syntax error or matching priorty? I appreciate any help.
Code:

```
// php 5.3
class Man {
    var $arr = array('name'=>'me');
}

$key = 'name';
$man = new Man();
echo $man->arr['name']; // output me
echo $man->$key['name']; // output nothing along with warning and notice

// output:
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'name' in php shell code on line 1
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Man::$n in php shell code on line 1
```

Comment: `$key` is `name`. There is **no property** `name` in `Man` class. That's why there's a warning. Also the above looks like PHP 4 syntax. please try to avoid it, your co-workers will be grateful.

Comment: PHP 7 have another output (`Notice: Undefined property: Man::$name`): https://3v4l.org/o5sgS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, do you mean `$key['name']` or `$man->$key` and `['name']` thereof? It's ambiguous syntax and PHP is interpreting it the former way, trying to get index `'name'` of string `'name'`, resulting in a warning being output and the interpretation being `'name'[0]`, i.e. `'n'`.

Disambiguate the syntax:

```
$man->{$key}['name']
```

Comment: @mover if you think this answer solved your problem, mark it as accepted by clicking the gray check icon.

Comment: It's some kind of Complex (curly) syntax. Here is the link:http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Comment: I think it is trying to get index `'name'` of string 'n' not string 'name'. When you don't provide brackets it only considers the first character of the string.

Comment: @Pooya *"Illegal string offset 'name'"* → it's trying to get the offset `['name']` of a string, clearly meaning it's trying `$key['name']` where `$key` is the string. Since `'name'` is an *invalid/illegal offset* of a string, it produces this warning. This is then falling back to interpreting the offset `'name'` as the next best numeric offset, which ends up being `0` (`(int)'name'` → `0`). So it results in `$key[0]`. Which then translates to `$man->n` and *"Undefined property: `Man::$n`"*. See https://3v4l.org/MFmgf.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't translate to anything because you're trying to access a property with a tag of a variable. It's not a variable, it won't work:

```
echo $man->$key['name'];
```

This on the other hand will work:

```
echo $man->{$key}['name'];
```

This lets php know the $key you're about to used is actually a property wrapped in {}

Comment: Thanks so much, César Ferreira.

Comment: Glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no name property define in your class. Because `echo $man->$key['name']; convert to echo name['name];`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Man {
    var $arr = array("name"=>"me");
}

$key = 'arr';
$man = new Man();
echo $man->arr['name']; // output me
echo $man->{$key}['name']; // output nothing along with warning and notice
```

Look how i used square brackets around `$key`. When you don't provide brackets it interprets to `$key[0]` :

`echo $man->a` but you can not access array values.

Comment: I think your explaination is not right here. $this->$key['name'] will interpret to "name['name']", but name doesn't have index 'name', so instead it return "name[0]", that is 'n'. Pls refer to the answer of deceze.

Comment: @Max look at my own example. `$key = 'arr'` And $arr already has index `name` but still php interprets `$key` to `$a`. just run my example without brackets and see the results. I hope you get it this time. just tell me if anything is unclear.

Comment: Sorry about that. Ignore my comments.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$man` is object of class if you want to print some it should be in class  try this code :

```
class Man{
    var $arr=array("name"=>"me");
}
$key='name';
$man=new Man;
echo $man->arr[$key]; //output me
```